# Questions about the concept behind the common cookie script

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am currently writing the cookies for the tag manager.
I found some good sources about creating cookies e.g in w3school. And I have a several question about the script:

1, For the last row of code in the setCookie function, does it means that the value e.g the number, will be stored in the variable document.cookie until it expires?

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

2, For the last row of code in the getCookie function

```
if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
```

What does it stand for?

3, Why there is a return "" at the end of the getCookie function?

The full code is as follows:

```
checkCookie()

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Many thanks for your help!